# Why NO jsx option in my WebStorm JavaScript version

Tags: webstorm

I tried reinstall my WebStorm, but it doesn't work.

```
WebStorm: 2021.2.1.
Device: Macbook Pro M1
```

[image: no jsx options]

Comment: Why do you think it should be there? If you would hit `F1` to see the help .. you would see that 1) NO JSX there at all: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/settings-languages-javascript.html 2) *"If you are using JSX syntax in your JavaScript code, enable ECMAScript 6+"* https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#ws_choose_language_version_jsx